# Angular2 + jspdf-autotable linebreak not working

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I just want to use **overflow: "linebreak"** options to my comment column here is my code

```
 var columns = [
        { title: "Date", dataKey: "date" },
        { title: "User", dataKey: "user" },
        { title: "Issue", dataKey: "issue" },
        { title: "Hours", dataKey: "hours" },
        { title: "Comment", dataKey: "comment" }

    ];
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.reports.length; i++) {
        var element = {
            date: 5,
            user: 5,
            issue: 3,
            hours: 2,
            comment:"dsfsudihfusidfhsyudfyhdysuyfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
        };
        rows.push(element);
    }
    var options = {
        overflow: "linebreak"
    }
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
        startY: doc.autoTable.previous.finalY + 15,
        margin: { horizontal: 7 },
        bodyStyles: { valign: 'top' },
        styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', columnWidth: 'wrap' },
        columnStyles: { text: { columnWidth: 'auto' } }
    });
    doc.save('table.pdf');
```

I copied this solution from them examples file https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js

But when I generate my pdf it looks like that
[image]

Comment: Try to use `overflow-wrap: break-word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `columnStyles: { text: { columnWidth: 'auto' } }` to `columnStyles: { comment: { columnWidth: 'auto' } }`

Comment: It works, thank you. Is there way to add an img from my solution folder, somethinkg like that
`doc.addImage('./resources/logo.png', 'png', 10, 15, 10, 10);`?